# Twilio Make an outbound call to a phone number cannot use url to play my own voice mp3

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I use Node v14.19.2
and this is my code

```
const accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID;
    const authToken = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN;
    const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

    const callResults = []

    // Use the Twilio API client to initiate the call
    for (let number of phoneNumbers) {
        number = number.toString().trim()
        number = number.startsWith('0') ? number.slice(1) : number
        number = '+66' + number
        const call = await client.calls.create({
            url: 'https://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3',
            to: number,
            from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER, // Twilio phone number from which to make the call
            timeout: 120
        });
        callResults.push(call)
    }
```

when I pickup up, I've always gotten same voice response (I think it's a default voice)
how to fix it to use url voice response

resolve my problem or the solution to figure out

Answer (score 0):

In order to play another mp3 of your voice, you'll have to [specify a new URL parameter in the request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#specify-a-url-parameter).

I'd recommend uploading your mp3 file to [Twilio Assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/assets#get-started-with-assets). When you do this, you'll get a URL for that asset which you can then pass into your request.